# How to make Phonegap app (with HTML5 and jQuery Mobile) fullscreen?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've created one Android app with Phonegap. I want to hide default notification bar when my App is running. In short I want to make my App fulscreen. I am using jQuery mobile. Can anyone suggest the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

> http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/toolbars/bars-fullscreen.html

Comment: Still in Android Footer is not bottom aligned, it jumps 10 px towards top every-time I tap on bottom nav :(

Comment: Thats a bug in jQuery mobile. Use the latest version

Comment: Try Using jQuery Mobile v 1.0